# Can I import scss file uses the 'composes' statement with Webpack?

Tags: css, sass, webpack, css-modules

I'm learning about CSS Modules at the moment, and they look like they will solve a lot of problems.  But all the documentation is based on CSS, I want to use SASS.

Is this possible? For example, how could I make the following statement work?

```
.normal {
    composes: common;
    composes: primary from "../shared/colors.scss";
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**./scss/import.scss**

```
.myImportClass {
    background-color: #f00
}
```

**./scss/style.scss**

```
.btn {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.newBtn {
    composes: btn;
    composes: myImportClass from './import.scss';
    border: 5px solid #f00;
}
```

**module part in your webpack.config.js**

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.scss/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader:'style-loader'
                },
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                    options: {
                        sourceMap: true,
                        modules: true,
                        localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
                    }
                },
                {
                    loader: 'sass-loader'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Your teststyle.js (ES6 / ES7):**

```
import React from 'react';
import style from './scss/style.scss';

const TestStyle = () => {
    render() {
        return (<div>
               <button className={style.newBtn}>my button</button>
        </div>)
    }
}

default export TestStyle;
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>webpack CSS composes</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**entry point app.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import TestStyle from './teststyle';

React.render(
     <TestStyle />,
     document.getElementById('app')
);
```

**// UPDATE**

- convert webpack config to webpack 3
- make teststyle.js a stateless function

Comment: Hey @phil, thanks for your answer.  The only thing is, you are using the 'composes' statement to extend a CSS class that is in the same file.  Is it possible to use it to reference another .scss file? e.g. _composes: primary from "../shared/colors.scss";_

Answer (score 0):

it's a problem of css-loader, try to add the option `importLoaders: 1,` in `css-loader` webpack config (https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#importloaders)

```
{
    loader: "css-loader",
    options: {
      modules: true,
      importLoaders: 1,
    },
  }
```